# Null pointer exception for Retrieving Data from mysql using servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

i am trying to Retrieving Data from my data base named  id  and it has a 2 columns uname and pass. i believe my beans class which is student is fine totally and as you can see pol class is for interacting with db and class dispach send the data to jsp,my problem is than when i am runing dispach on server i get the NullPointerException

```js
public class pol {

    public List<student> getstudent() throws Exception {

        List<student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pooya";

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement s = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");

            String sql = "select * from id";

            s = connection.createStatement();
            s.executeQuery(sql);

            rs = s.getResultSet();

            while (rs.next()) {

                String uname = rs.getString("uname");
                String pass = rs.getString("pass");
                student tempstudent = new student(uname, pass);
                students.add(tempstudent);

            }
            return students;

        } finally {
            // close JDBC objects
            close(connection, s, rs);
        }
    }

    private void close(Connection connection, Statement s, ResultSet rs) {

        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }

            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();   // doesn't really close it ... just puts back in connection pool
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```js
public class dispach extends HttpServlet {
    private java java;
    private pol pol;

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/web_student_tracker")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            java = new java(dataSource);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            listteacher(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void listteacher(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        List<student> student = pol.getstudent();
        request.setAttribute("select", student);
        //fix
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/NewFile.jsp");

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <c:forEach var="tempstudent" items="${select}">
        <tr>
            <td>${tempstudent.uname}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When asking for help about an exception, include the stack trace. In particular, point out which line it matches to in your pastes. Also, exceptions have 4 useful bits of info: Type, message, trace, cause. By going 'e.printStackTrace()' you are chucking 3 out of the 4 useful things, so stop doing this, it is a sign of bad code and makes finding causes of problems very difficult. If you don't know how to handle one, the fallback is 'throw new RuntimeException(e)', _NOT_ 'e.printStackTrace()'.

Comment: thanks for your comment i changed my code as you said and now this is what i got 'SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [response.dispach] in context with path [/table] threw exception'. in class dispach line 44 it throws exceptions

Comment: If you stop writing e.printStackTrace() everywhere, you'd get actual info about what went wrong and where it happened. Here's a good rule of thumb: Until you've been programming java for 2 years or more, you are not allowed to write the letters 'printStackTrace'. ever. no excuses.

Comment: i understood your point but i am lost about  where should i start to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `pol` member variable in this line `List<student> student = pol.getstudent();` in `dispatch#listteacher` method, but it has not yet been initialized. You have to initialize it first (in constructor, or some other way) to be able to call methods on it, else you will indeed get a `NullPointerException`.

Also consider to name your classes kebab-cased, e.g. `Dispatch` instead of `dispatch`. That is the Java class naming convention.

Comment: can you tell em how can i initialize it?

Comment: You can do `this.pol = new pol();` in your `init` method in the `dispatch` class (just as you do with the `java` member variable).

Comment: it works! i have the value of my table on display but my data suppose to go to my jsp file which is NewFile.jsp. when i run the dispach class the url is still on servlet not on jsp. could you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, this could be because of many things. Are you using servlets for a specific reason? If not, I would suggest to getting into learning a framework like Spring MVC or Spring Boot. With Spring Boot it's pretty simple to setup a basic Model View Controller example that just runs almost out-of-the-box (see https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ for more information). If you have to use servlets for whatever reason, then I would suggest asking a new question with example code etc. provided.

Comment: i am doing a student project with servlet but as soon as possible i will shift to spring . do you think learning servlet deeply is import for starting a spring framework?

Comment: Ah, right, that's why servlets. No, you don't need deep understanding of servlets to start with Spring. Knowing HTTP servlets will help you in understanding how the HTTP stuff works, which is considered a plus when starting with Spring, but you definitely don't need deep understanding of it when starting with Spring. In my opinion, you don't need to know anything about servlets when starting with Spring. You probably will learn the basics of servlets on the go with Spring sooner or later anyway.